# How to run contexBroker Orion in a Raspbian OS?

Tags: raspbian, fiware, fiware-orion

Is there any possibility of running Orion ContextBroker on Raspberry Pi with Raspbian OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirements recommended in the [Orion documentation](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/diagnosis/index.html##resource-availability) are:

> Although we haven't done yet a precise profiling on Orion Context
>   Broker,  tests done in our development and testing environment show
>   that a host with  **2 CPU cores and 4 GB RAM** is fine to run the
>   ContextBroker and MongoDB server. In fact, this is a rather
>   conservative estimation, Orion Context Broker could run fine also in
>   systems with a lower resources profile. The critical resource here is
>   RAM memory, as MongoDB performance is related to the amount of
>   available RAM to map database files into memory.

Besides the board constrained resources, you will have to search about the equivalent [required libraries](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/build_source/index.html) for RaspbianOS.

There is a discussion about it here:
https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/15

Comment: I have a vague remembrance (it was much time ago) that MongoDB has some problems to run in Raspberry Pi. Something related with an architecture difference (32 vs 64 bits). However, maybe Raspberry Pi has evolved since that and currently there isn't any problem. In addition, you can run MongoDB outside Rasbperry Pi, of course.